# How to get raw_input() in a specific position of command line

Tags: python

I am making a simple high score system for a game.
I am using "colorama" to print text in a specific position of command line.
How can I get input in a specific position of command line?

```
score = 15
print '\033[10;20H{}'.format("Game over")
if score > 10:
    name = raw_input("Enter your name: ") #I want to get this in the position y = 11 , x = 20
    print '\033[12;12H{}'.format("Your score was added to high scores")
```

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking. Have you tried adding spaces to the `raw_input` prompt, or using the same format string your use for printing? Also, you might want to have a look at the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) module

Comment: I want to print "Enter your name: " in the middle of console so when user is entering the name, name is being showed in the center of command line.

Comment: Google `python curses`.